# Map scatter as a subplot in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, matplotlib-basemap, subplot

I have a grouped dataframe which contains value, lat, lon and year variables. I want to plot values at different locations per year on a map.

```
This is how my dataframe looks:
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

dtype: object
          lat        lon                      Date       mean  Year
0   2.912811  7.609220 2017-12-31 00:00:00+05:30  27.146307  2017
1   2.938906  7.697270 2017-12-31 00:00:00+05:30  19.067468  2016
```

This is what I am doing to plot data from 2016 to 2019 in 4 subplots:
df_yearly.dropna()

```
#Data to be shown on the map:
#fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.5,9.0))
fig_title = 'Combined_map.pdf'
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, figsize=(12, 8))


year_start=2016
year_stop=2019

for i in range (1,5):

  #for year in range(year_start, year_stop+1):
    for year in df_yearly['Year']:
      #print (year)
      data = np.array(conc)
      #create figure and axes instances                                                                                                                               
      plot_location = '22'+ str(i)
      print ('plot_location: '), 
      print (plot_location)

     #plt.subplot(plot_location)
      plt.tight_layout()


    #create polar stereographic Basemap instance                                                                                                                    
      m = Basemap(projection='mill',llcrnrlat=0,urcrnrlat=60,llcrnrlon=70,urcrnrlon=11, resolution='c')

# draw coastlines, state and country boundaries, edge of map.                                                                                                   
      m.drawcoastlines(linewidth =1.5, color ="black")
      m.drawcountries(linewidth =1.5, color ="black")

      m.drawmapboundary()

 #Scatter:
      m.scatter(lon, lat, latlon=True,c=np.array(conc),
              cmap='jet', alpha=2)


# 3. create colorbar and legend
      plt.colorbar(label=r'$Concentration$')
      plt.clim(0, 200)
      ptitle = "concentrations: "+str(year)     
      plt.title(ptitle, fontsize=7, weight='bold')

#plt.show()
plt.savefig(fig_title,bbox_inches="tight")        

print ('Plotted:'), (fig_title)
```

How to have values from different years plotted in different scatter map subplots?

Comment: Can you add your imports please, where is `Basemap` coming from? Also what do you mean by _"How to have only 4 plots with lat lon information?"_ - how many plots do you have currently?

Comment: I am not getting anything plotted. All I see is 3 empty subplots and 4th subplot which is probably a montage of all the plots.

Comment: At a guess, try passing `m.scatter` something like `ax=axes[row, col]`. You need to figure out row and col sensibly yourself which shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Does not seem to work. Do I need to create an additional dimension for location in my data, being plotted as numpy array ?

Comment: It looks like it should work based on [the docs](https://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subplots.html#generating-the-subplots-at-the-beginning-with-plt-subplots) - they are passing the `ax=axes[row, col]` kwarg to `Basemap` directly, not to `m.scatter.